# Yii - user side validation for ajax loaded form elements

Tags: php, jquery, validation, yii

I'm using Yii user side validation in static forms and it's great. 
But I don't know how to add validators for ajax loaded elements.

I have simple form widget and I would like to load few more input fields into it via AJAX (that's not problem with small jQuery script). But I don't know how to add Yii javascript validators for loaded elements - I mean auto created JS validators like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function($) {
$('#newsletter-form-footer').yiiactiveform({'validateOnSubmit':true,'validateOnChange':false,'afterValidate':Form.handleByAjax,'attributes':[{'id':'NewsletterForm_emailaddress','inputID':'NewsletterForm_emailaddress','errorID':'NewsletterForm_emailaddress_em_','model':'NewsletterForm','name':'emailaddress','enableAjaxValidation':false,'clientValidation':function(value, messages, attribute) {

if($.trim(value)=='') {
    messages.push("  VALIDATOR_REQUIRED");
}


if($.trim(value)!='' && !value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$/)) {
    messages.push("  VALIDATOR_EMAIL");
}

}}]});
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Is there any way how to add or remove that validators?

Comment: Add the validators in the standard manner: by rendering a view that uses appropriate input element renderes (e.g. with [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeTextField-detail) and similar methods or through `CActiveForm`)

Comment: I have them already. But I have another problem:
I have validators for elements: 
`$email = new Yp_Form_Element(Yp_Form_Element::FIELD_textField, 'email', $this);
$email->setRequired()`
But Yii create javascript client side validation script after rendering page. But I need to add something to this script for ajax loaded elements.

Comment: How about render all inputs and hide them using jquery, instead of loading them through ajax. if there are not too many.

Comment: @Asgaroth it's not good solution - I would have about 50 inputs if I do it your way...

Answer (score 0):

This is little bit tricky... If you want to do it using yiiactiveform, you have to:

1. Add a field to validation, or
2. Remove a field from validation

My suggestion is:

1. Create your own JavaScript validation functions (you may want to copy yii's validation code here)

   ```
   $('#newsletter-form-footer').submit(function() {
           return MyValidator.validate();
   });
   ```
2. When you load a field into the form

   ```
   //You have to get rulesORoptions
   // along with fieldName from your ajax request.
   MyValidator.add(fieldName, rulesORoptions);
   ```
3. When you Remove a field out of the form

   ```
   MyValidator.remove(fieldName);
   ```
4. MyValidator code here...

   ```
   var MyValidator = {
           fields: {},

           add: function(fieldName, rulesORoptions) {
                   this.fields[fieldName] = rulesORoptions;
           },
           remove: function(fieldName) {
                   delete this.fields[fieldName];
           },

           validate: function() {
                   var success = true;
                   for(var fieldName in this.fields) {
                           for(var rule in this.fields[fieldName]) {

                                   if( eval('MyValidator.'+rule+'($("#'+fieldName+'").val())') == false ) {
                                           $("#'+fieldName+'_em_").html("validation failed (some error text, rulesORoptions may contain error text )");
                                           success = false;
                                   }
                           }
                   }

                   return success;
           },

           /* Validation methods are here, 
              copy the javascript validation code from Yii
           */
           email: function(value) {
                   if($.trim(value)!='' && !value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$/)) {
                           return false;
                   }

                   return true;
           },
           required: function(value) {
                   if($.trim(value)=='') {
                           return false;
                   }

                   return true;
           },
           number: function(value) {
                   if(/*copy yii validation code */) {
                           return false;
                   }

                   return true;
           },
           .....
           .....
   };
   ```