# Yii: Ajax validation on dynamically created fields

Tags: jquery, yii, validation

I have a form created with CActiveForm and the HTML output is something like this

```
...
    <tr>
        <td><input class="span9" placeholder="Type in the seminar title" name="CvSeminar[0][title]" id="CvSeminar_0_title" maxlength="255" value="Some Value" type="text">        <span class="help-inline error" id="CvSeminar_0_title_em_" style="display: none"></span>    </td>
        <td><input class="span1" name="CvSeminar[0][yearIssued]" id="CvSeminar_0_yearIssued" maxlength="4" value="2009" type="text">        <span class="help-inline error" id="CvSeminar_0_yearIssued_em_" style="display: none"></span>    </td>
        <td><a href="#" class="removeSeminarRow"><i style="margin-top: 10px" class="icon-remove"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="span9" placeholder="Type in the seminar title" name="CvSeminar[1][title]" id="CvSeminar_1_title" maxlength="255" value="Some Value" type="text">        <span class="help-inline error" id="CvSeminar_1_title_em_" style="display: none"></span>    </td>
        <td><input class="span1" name="CvSeminar[1][yearIssued]" id="CvSeminar_1_yearIssued" maxlength="4" value="2006" type="text">        <span class="help-inline error" id="CvSeminar_1_yearIssued_em_" style="display: none"></span>    </td>
        <td><a href="#" class="removeSeminarRow"><i style="margin-top: 10px" class="icon-remove"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
...
```

As you can see i create an area where each row cantains two fields. I have also created a button where a user can add a new row. The html output when the user hits the button is:

```
<tr>
   <td><input class="span9" placeholder="Type in the seminar title" name="CvSeminar[1000][title]" id="CvSeminar_1000_title" maxlength="255" type="text"><span class="help-inline error" id="CvSeminar_1000_title_em_" style="display: none"></span></td>
   <td><input class="span1" name="CvSeminar[1000][yearIssued]" id="CvSeminar_1000_yearIssued" maxlength="4" type="text"><span class="help-inline error" id="CvSeminar_1000_yearIssued_em_" style="display: none"></span></td>
   <td><a href="#" class="removeSeminarRow"><i style="margin-top: 10px" class="icon-remove"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

My problem starts when i create a new row and leave it empty. The Ajax validation on server side works fine. Yii responds with json that the new field has errors.

```
{"CvSeminar_1000_title":["Title cannot be empty."],"CvSeminar_1000_yearIssued":["Year cannot be empty"]}
```

The problem is on client side. Since yiiactiveform does know nothing about the new added row, how can I update yiiactiveform to include the newly added fields ?

Thanks

Comment: similar question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003247/yii-user-side-validation-for-ajax-loaded-form-elements/12353297

Comment: @SuVeRa well i have read this, but i do not want to create my own validator... Is there a way to do it with yiiactiveform ?

Comment: @antoniom question title says ajax validation problem and content says client validation. Clarify

Comment: @dInGd0nG When ajax validation is triggered server does the actual validation. However client gets the validation messages encoded in json in order to present them. So, `client side` means that the javascript receiving the json message does not handle it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the new row just update the form settings with the new attribute to validate.

```
var settings = $(myform).data('settings');
settings.attributes.push({
   ...Validation settings here
});
$(myform).data('settings', settings);
```

Have a look at the javascript Yii generates so you know what to use.

Comment: Nice idea, As soon as I test it, I will let you know!

Comment: Yes the proposed method works! However it is quite exhausting to add all validation setting. See for example: `{
                    "id":"CvLanguage_1000_language",
                    "inputID":"CvLanguage_1000_language",
                    "errorID":"CvLanguage_1000_language_em_",
                    "model":"CvLanguage",
                    "name":"CvLanguage[1000][language]",
                    "enableAjaxValidation":true,
                    "inputContainer":"div.control-group",
                    "status":1
                }` This is only a rule for only one field!

Comment: Anyway I think that this approach is more appropriate than the one I proposed, however is a little more difficult to implement. My +100 reputation is yours!

Comment: I would make a base object with default settings.     var base = {"enableAjaxValidation: true, "status": 1, "model":"CvLanguage"}    then use jQuery's extend, var newRow = $.extend({id: "..."}, base); etc.  And to generate id's   var idcount = 2; function nextid() {return 'CvLanguage_' + (idcount++) + '_language';}

Comment: This will not work if you want to validate new fields `onChange`, and if you re initialize `yiiactiveform` it will do double validation of form fields that are already have been validating

Answer (score 0):

Well, after lot of research I have found a solution. Not the best one, but surely the most clean of all.

Since `yiiactiveform` does know nothing about the `CvSeminar_1000_title` and `CvSeminar_1000_yearIssued` I have created it beforehand:

```
for($i = 1000; $i <= 1050; $i++) {
    $form->textField(new CvSeminar, '['.$i.']title'); 
    $form->error(new CvSeminar, '['.$i.']title'); 
    $form->textField(new CvSeminar, '['.$i.']yearIssued');
    $form->error(new CvSeminar, '['.$i.']yearIssued');
}
```

- Note 1: Yes, I know! It's not the best solution, but it works fine!
- Note 2: I am not echoing the form elements, just calling the methods in order to force `CActiveForm` to create the appropriate js ajax validation.

Comment: That is an interesting problem, and your solution is probably "okay" if you do not have too many elements. However, I believe they will be used by the jquery.yiicactiveform method, so you have a higher Javascript load. The cleaner solution would be to create the models on the fly on the server-side when validating, and to add them to the Active Form after they have been created by your cloning mechanism. But this looks like quite a hassle from a quick glance into the js code.

Comment: @Narretz The problem is with jquery.yiiactiveform.js found under the ./web/js/source folder in the yii framework. If you look at this script there is no method so you can add an element dynamically after the form is created.